# Barchart don't show correctly

Tags: javafx

Hello I have a Barchart in JavaFx, the Data Show just fine when is directly loaded in the initialize method, but When I Load a MouseEvent, the Date label does not show correctly. I Put here a minimized example.

this is my code in `IncidentesController`

```
    @FXML private ComboBox<String> solicitudindc;
          @FXML private JFXButton generarind;
          @FXML private BarChart <String,Integer> indicadorsoporte;
          @FXML private  CategoryAxis fechas;
          @FXML private NumberAxis cantidades;


            public void generaindicador() {
            String Bd="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP- 
            8PJDQNJ:1433;databaseName=QUORA";
            String Usuario="myuser";
            String Pass="mypass";
            String Query= "SELECT FECHA_EJECUTADA ,  COUNT(PRIORIDAD) AS CANTIDAD FROM RINCIDENTES WHERE PRIORIDAD='ALTA' GROUP BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ORDER BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ASC"; 
            String Query2= "SELECT FECHA_EJECUTADA ,  COUNT(PRIORIDAD) AS CANTIDAD FROM RINCIDENTES WHERE PRIORIDAD='MEDIA' GROUP BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ORDER BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ASC"; 
            XYChart.Series<String,Integer> DatosPrioridad = new Series<String,Integer> ();
            XYChart.Series<String,Integer> DatosPrioridad2 = new Series<String,Integer> ();
            
            Connection Conexiontabla = null;
            try {
                 ............conection code...........
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String y=rs.getString("FECHA_EJECUTADA");
                    int a=rs.getInt("CANTIDAD");
                    DatosPrioridad.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(y,a) );
                }
                indicadorsoporte.getData().add(DatosPrioridad);
                DatosPrioridad.setName("PRIORIDAD ALTA");
               }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
            
            
             try {
               ............conection code...........
                while (rss.next()) {
                    String x=rss.getString("FECHA_EJECUTADA");
                    int z=rss.getInt("CANTIDAD");
                    DatosPrioridad2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(x,z) );
                   
                }
                indicadorsoporte.getData().add(DatosPrioridad2);
                DatosPrioridad2.setName("PRIORIDAD MEDIA");
                fechas.setLabel("Fechas");
                cantidades.setLabel("Cantidades");
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
```

If the Combobox have the value `"REPORTE DE INCIDENTES"` I load the barchart like this:

```
public void generaincidentes() {
     generarind.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
          if(solicitudindc.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("REPORTE DE INCIDENTES")) {
              generaindicador();
          }
          });  
  }
```

this are the images:

when i load directly in the initialize method:
[image]

when I select the option in the combobox to load the Barchart:
[image]

any guidance?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

This work for me!:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Integer>>
  getdatosbarchart() {
        String Bd="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-8PJDQNJ:1433;databaseName=QUORA";
        String Usuario="sa";
        String Pass="milkas87";
        String Query= "SELECT FECHA_EJECUTADA ,  COUNT(PRIORIDAD) AS CANTIDAD FROM RINCIDENTES WHERE PRIORIDAD='ALTA'  GROUP BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ORDER BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ASC"; 
        String Query2= "SELECT FECHA_EJECUTADA ,  COUNT(PRIORIDAD) AS CANTIDAD FROM RINCIDENTES WHERE PRIORIDAD='MEDIA' GROUP BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ORDER BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ASC"; 
        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Integer>> data =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Series<String, Integer> as = new Series<>();
        Series<String, Integer> bs = new Series<>();
        Connection Conexiontabla = null;
        try {
            Conexiontabla=DriverManager.getConnection(Bd, Usuario, Pass);
            PreparedStatement ps =Conexiontabla.prepareStatement(Query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String y=rs.getString("FECHA_EJECUTADA");
                int a=rs.getInt("CANTIDAD");
                as.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(y,a) ); 
            }
            as.setName("PRIORIDAD ALTA");
         }catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         try {
                Conexiontabla=DriverManager.getConnection(Bd, Usuario, Pass);
                PreparedStatement pd =Conexiontabla.prepareStatement(Query2);
                ResultSet rss = pd.executeQuery();
            while (rss.next()) {
                String y=rss.getString("FECHA_EJECUTADA");
                int a=rss.getInt("CANTIDAD");
                bs.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(y,a) );
            }
            bs.setName("PRIORIDAD MEDIA");
            fechas.setLabel("Fechas");
            cantidades.setLabel("Cantidades");
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         data.addAll(as,bs);
        return data;    
  }

  public BarChart<String, Integer>crearbarchart() {
    indicadorsoporte.setData(getdatosbarchart());
    indicadorsoporte.setTitle("Soportes realizados en el Mes");
    return indicadorsoporte;
}
```